# Angular Universal dev:ssr works fine but serve:ssr shows .js

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I will try to explain. When I use the Angular Universal dev:ssr script to test the performance, the page code in the browser shows the content.

But after doing the build:ssr and server:ssr it does not. What it shows are the angular files: main.js, etc.

I leave here the scripts, and part of the code to see if you can help me.

I have tried to use prerender with all pages, but the GDPR dialog is the only thing that shows up.

Thank you very much, first of all.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Production (serve:ssr):
[image]

Comment: check if any error in server.js console ,may be app not rendering well

Comment: No errors on Browser console. Server pm2 i saw something about url that not found. Noting more.

Comment: if any error occur during server start up it broken app initialization, fix it or just comment it and check again